# View all functions defined in a Haskell file

Tags: haskell, reflection

I'm learning functional programming by learning Haskell. For practicing the syntax and structuring very simple functions, I've created a small file; let's say it looks something like this:

```
removeOdd nums =
  if null nums
    then []
    else
      if (mod (head nums) 2) == 0 --is even?
        then (head nums) : (removeOdd (tail nums))
        else removeOdd (tail nums)

removeOddGuards [] = []
removeOddGuards (x : xs)
  | mod x 2 == 0 = x : (removeOdd xs)
  | otherwise    = removeOdd xs

double nums = case nums of
  []       -> []
  (x : xs) -> (2 * x) : (double xs)
```

I would like to define a function which returns a list of all of the names of functions defined in the file, like:

```
["removeOdd", "removeOddGuards", "double"]
```

I suppose I would implement reflection in an object-oriented language, but am as of yet too naïve to understand if this is even a valid concept in functional programming.

For practical purposes, I'd like to be able to call such a function to see a basic index of the functions I've created in this practice file.

Comment: [Template Haskell](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#template-haskell) can do this, but it's an advanced topic. Why do you want to define such a function? There's probably a simpler way of achieving your actual goal.

Comment: Thanks; just curious about how complex such a task would be, more or less, and looking for a quick way see a list of the functions I've defined in this practice file.

Comment: Would using `:browse ModuleName` be enough for your purpose? Reflection is not commonly used in FP. Do you really need it?

Comment: [Haddock](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/#Overview) is probably the simplest way to get a nice HTML list of all the functions in a module. There's also `ghci`'s `:bro` command. The language itself doesn't provide built-in reflection capabilities - what you want isn't _easy_ - because thanks to Haskell's unique powers of abstraction there are usually better ways of writing code which in other languages would require reflection.

Comment: Thanks guys. Using `:browse` in ghci works great as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you don't want to define and execute a function but you simply want to see what functions you have defined in a file. Say your definitions above are in `foo.hs`. This is how you can see what functions you have defined:

```
$ ghci foo.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :browse
removeOdd :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
removeOddGuards :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
double :: Num t => [t] -> [t]
*Main>
```

Comment: You may want to note that `:browse` can take a module name as an argument.